# When using netty for a large file upload, how can I get uploaded size while upload is in progress?

Tags: netty

If I can get the temporary location of the file during the upload, I can check the size. But, I am getting the temporary file location only when LastHttpContent is received and by doing `decoder.next()`

Is there any way I could get the file name in advance?

I am running the sample code from https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/upload/HttpUploadServerHandler.java

I would like to get the upload percentage in writeHttpData if the datatype is FileUpload

Comment: Can you add some code what exactly you are doing ?

Comment: @NormanMaurer Thanks for the response. Added sample code reference.

Comment: Currently, indeed, the file during upload is not available while being processed (since masked by `decoder.offer(chunk)`), even if using hasNext() since it is not yet available.

Comment: Currently, indeed, the file during upload is not available while being processed (since masked by `decoder.offer(chunk)` and `decoder.hasNext() ko since not yet available). One could propose an improvement as a combination of sthg close to `decoder.isCurrentFileUpload()`, `decoder.currentFileUpload()` which then will allow to check `fileUpload.length()` for current size and adding (missing ?) `fileUpload.definedSize()` for announced final size (but take care since if in 7bit for instance, might be 7bit encoded file size, not final file size, so percentage might be wrong).

Comment: Thanks @FredericBrégier. I will create an issue on github for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @frederic mentioned in the comment, right now its not possible.

created the following issue on github
https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/3636